# How can I fix the following formatting problem with the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, bibliographies, chapters, indexing

I have a few unnumbered chapters that I would like to add to the table of contents. This is not a problem at the moment, because of someone graciously providing the following macro, which adds the unnamed chapter with the correct horizontal alignment (i.e., it is aligned with the rest of the chapter titles and not numbers):

```
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\addchap}{ s o m }{%
    \typeout{providing a minimal version of addchapp.
        You might want to use a KOMA class for full
        features
    }%
    \chapter*{#3}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \markboth{}{}
    }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#3}
            \markboth{#3}{#3}%
        }{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
            \markboth{#2}{#2}%
        }
    }
}
```

I then need to use:

```
\addchap{{Preface}}
```

The problem I have is with other unnamed chapters.

The first is the index. I can't use `\addchap` for the index, because it uses

```
\begin{theindex}
\end{theindex}
```

based on an `.ind` file. So, my first question is: how to make sure that `\begin{theindex}` uses `\addchap` instead of chapter or whatever else it is using?

My second issue is with references.

I am currently using the following commands:

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{myref}
```

which does the job (it adds a new chapter called `Bibliography`), but it doesn't add anything to the table of contents. Again, I suspect I need to make a change so that the bibliography command uses `\addchap` instead of whatever else it is using.

Any fixes for these two issues?

Comment: `\theindex` uses a `\chapter*{\indexname}` most likely -- you have to kick out that definition. Can you specify who 'someone' was? The other issue can be done with `\usepackage{tocbibind}`

Comment: how `\chapter*` is handled with respect to the toc depends on the document class you are using.  `tocbibind` will probably do what you need, but make sure first that it is compatible with your document class.  (that is why it's a good idea to specify that when asking a question.)

Answer (score 2):

The `tocbibind` package provides the means automatically to include `index` and `bibliography` in the ToC.

The command `\addchap` is only needed when not using the KOMA classes (and is ignored, when KOMA is loaded)

Here is the content of `myref.bib`

```
 @Book{Knuth:90,
        author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
        title     = {The {\TeX}book},
        year      = {1990},
        publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
    }
    @Book{Lamport:94,
        author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
        title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
        year      = {1994},
        publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
    }
```

---

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ProvideDocumentCommand{\addchap}{ s o m }{%
    \typeout{providing a minimal version of addchapp.
        You might want to use a KOMA class for full
        features
    }%
    \chapter*{#3}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
        \markboth{}{}%
    }{%
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#3}%
            \markboth{#3}{#3}%
        }{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}%
            \markboth{#2}{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}%


\makeindex



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument
\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}

\chapter{Dummy chapter}
In his book \cite{Knuth:90}

\index{dummyindex}
\section{Dummy section}

\printindex



\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{myref}




\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have lots of unprotected end-of-lines that may produce spaces in the output (I know they're already in the OP's macro, but it's not a justification). You should also call `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` in order to avoid the abomination of having the table of contents listed in the table of contents.

Comment: Now there are too many. `;-)` For instance, the one after `\chapter*{#3}` can safely be omitted, but it doesn't hurt. The final one is really awful (expert TeX programmers notice it as a punch in the eye). `;-)`

Comment: thanks, but this is not quite what I am looking for, since I want the Index, Bibliography and Unnumbered Chapter titles to be aligned with the *text* of the numbered chapters, and not their numbers...